# Open source programs to apply vector designs into mockups?

Tags: vector, mockup, open-source

I create mostly logo designs using Inkscape on Linux but I cannot find a way to mockup my designs with an open source software. Are there any open source programs to apply vector (or raster) designs into mockups for showcasing designs? Similar to what Photoshop calls ['Smart Objects.'](https://www.mockupworld.co/all-mockups/)

Comment: Why do you need something like Photoshop's Smart Objects?  Can't you import the SVG into GIMP and transform the perspective to fit it to the object?

Comment: @BillyKerr I have tried transforming with GIMP and Inkscape but never could not achieve good results. The mockups I need use more than just perspective, they include lighting, texture morph etc.

Comment: Maybe [Placeit.net](https://placeit.net/) has something you could use?

Comment: GIMP has a lighting filter, and you can use layer modes for textures, and you can morph images onto textured surfaces using a displacement map, or a bump map, almost exactly the same as can be done in Photoshop.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://i.imgur.com/dQBi8yx.jpg) of the kind of thing that can be done in GIMP.  It's quite simple, a bump map, some drop shadows, some masking, use of the blur tool, etc.  Obviously, there's no smart object stuff, where you can just replace the smart object, and all the effects are applied. In GIMP you'd need to make edits manually for each mockup.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, depends on what do you mean by showcasing your designs and what those designs are.

My option would be, create your mockup.

If there are no macros or smart objects on Gimp to reproduce shades and perspectives, my option would be to generate a full 3D object.

Prepare some 3D models, for flat logos, for business cards, for a flyer on **Blender**.

Then you only need to change the base texture and generate a new render with the new design.

Answer (score 0):

Many programs open PSDs, for ex. GIMP, Krita, Paint.NET, Serif Affinity Photo & -Design(not free, only low cost), but the result is partial. They do not interpret properly  Photoshop's advanced side such as vector masks, smart filters and layer styles. Normal raster layers and layer blending modes are interpreted ok as long as the program knows the used color system and the blending mode.

That's unfortunate, because many high quality PSD mockups are based on PS's advanced features. A good mockup can radically reduce the needed not-so-creative work, you get right bendings, perspective, lights&shadows and texture overlay virtually with no work. Add only your colors, texts and the design drawing, tweak the effect strengths as you like.

Your options:

- get Photoshop - even for a short time, it's now rented, you cannot buy it except pre-CC versions (poor SVG support) as second hand stuff. If you haven't already used it, you have a short fully free trial period.
- test the available mockups "what you get in GIMP or other available software which reads PSDs". Rebuild the missing things such as the perspective and light with program's own methods
- start from scratch. That's a long term solution and will be a substantial skill level jump, too. Usable mockups can be built without smart filters and layer styles.

Comment: Photoshop doesn't work on Linux.

Comment: @BillyKerr are you sure? Linux has windows emulators and virtual machines. (Of course virtual machine needs finally windows, but one can run an exported copy of an old WIn system which are low cost stuff) See this: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-adobe-photoshop-linux/

Comment: You might be able to get an older version to work via Wine, but no guarantees. Adobe certainly doesn't support it.

Comment: @BillyKerr ok. I suspect that the performance is poor if it works.  One can get angry when he waits a stack of effects being calculated without the help of videogame graphic processing in the video card.

Comment: @user287001 you can easily get the computer to feel like the virtual windows was native if you allocate it its own ssd. And virtualisation can use the graphics card.

Comment: @joojaa I believe many would be glad if they had a Win in Linux system which runs graphics faster than  like a louse in tar. Can you insert a couple of good search terms or even links?